# How do I enable Shady DOM in Polymer 2.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, shady-dom

Polymer 1.x uses *Shady DOM* by default, but that could be changed at initialization by setting the `window.Polymer` object before importing `polymer.html` as follows:

```
<script>window.Polymer = {dom: 'shadow'};</script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer.html">
```

However, it seems Polymer 2.0 uses *Shadow DOM* regardless of `window.Polymer = {dom: 'shady'}`. How do I switch to Shady DOM?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Shady DOM shim was [factored out of Polymer in 2.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#shadow-dom-v1) and moved into the v1 Web Components polyfill.

To enable Shady DOM (instead of the default Shadow DOM), define the following `window.ShadyDOM` object before importing the v1 `webcomponents-lite.js`:

```
<script>window.ShadyDOM = { force: true };</script>
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LbBOxm?editors=1010)

**UPDATE:** A simpler setting is to specify `[shadydom]` on the `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js" shadydom></script>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QMmMxJ?editors=1000)